# Satmar Rav in Divrei Yoel: the goal of Eretz Yisrael

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, translation, eretz-yisrael, satmar

[This article](https://www.truetorahjews.org/divrei-yoel-parashas-pinchas) on Parashas Pinchas quotes the Satmar Rav in Divrei Yoel, vol. 6, where it says:

> The Satmar Rebbe, ZY"A, in [Divrei Yoel (Parashas Emor pp. 184-185)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21095&st=&pgnum=185) decries the false ideas surrounding Eretz Yisroel and explains clearly the concept of Eretz Yisroel. The Rebbe teaches that Eretz Yisroel was given to the Jewish People solely in order that they should learn Torah, do mitzvos, and raise ehrliche Yiddishe generations there, bringing glory and honor to the holy Name of Hashem and spreading knowledge of the truth of Hashem throughout the world. When we fail in this endeavor, drifting from this ideal state of existence in Eretz Yisroel, we cause, chas v'shalom, a desecration of Hashem's holy Name.

2. This might be the real question, since (1) is more of a "helping hand". Are there other sources that convey the same, or almost same view of the Satmar Rav, e.g. that "**Eretz Yisroel was given to the Jewish People solely in order that they should learn Torah, do mitzvos, and raise ehrliche Yiddishe generations there, bringing glory and honor to the holy Name of Hashem and spreading knowledge of the truth of Hashem throughout the world.**"

---

1. My Hebrew is not that good at this point, it is getting beter, so    I am not able to locate the exact location of this explanation from    the Satmar Rav. Can someone translate for me the exact location of    these words? (**Thanks to @Dov for providing a translation. Q1 no longer necessary)**

Comment: It's not in yiddish?

Comment: @dov my bad, changed it

Comment: "Are there other sources that convey the same, or almost same view of the Satmar Rav" This is a running thread through the work [אם הבנים שמחה](https://hebrewbooks.org/53692) by [R. Yissakhar Shelomo Teichtal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yissachar_Shlomo_Teichtal). He however came to a very different conclusion than R. Teitelbaum as regards getting there.

Comment: +1 for Eim Habanim Smeicha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> וזה יהיה ביאור הכתוב ושמרתם וגו' ולא תקיא אתכם הארץ אשר אני מביא אתכם שמה לשבת בה, דבא הכתוב להזהיר את ישראל על שמירת התורה והמצוות, ועל גידול הבנים בדרכי התורה והקדושה, ולכוונה זו אמר אשר אני מביא אתכם שמה לשבת בה. כי כל מה שהביא הקב"ה את בני ישראל לארץ ישראל היה בעבור תכלית אחת, שיתפרסם ויתגלה כבוד מלכותו ואלקותו יתברך בעולם כולו, ע"י עם סגולתו המקדשים שמו בעולם, בקבלת עול מלכותו עליהם, ובשמירת תורתו ומצוותיו, שע"י כן שמו יתברך נקרא עלינו. ובעבור כן חייבים ישראל לגדל דורות נאמנים לתורת ה', אשר על ידיהם יתקדש שם שמים בעולם
>
> And this is the explanation behind the verse "[And you shall guard (all My laws and all My regulations)](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.20.22?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)..." etc. - lest the land to which I bring you to settle in spew you out, The verse said to warn Israel about keeping the Torah and the mitzvos, and about raising the sons in the ways of the Torah and holiness, and for this purpose He said "I am bringing you there to dwell in it", because everything that G-d brought the children of Israel to the Land of Israel was for one purpose; so that the glory of His majesty be made known and revealed, and may his G-dliness be blessed in the entire world, through His chosen people who sanctify His name in the world, by accepting the burden of His kingdom upon themselves, and by keeping his Torah and commandments, through which His blessed name is called upon us. And for that, Israel must raise generations faithful to the Torah of God, through whom the sake of Heaven will be sanctified in the world.

Comment: Thanks Dov, much appreciated. I feel almost stupid asking for translations, but I am still learning Hebrew. Are you aware of a similair concept being explained elsewhere, e.g. that Eretz Yisroel was given to the Jewish People solely in order that they should learn Torah. If so, please feel free to add that in :). Hatzlacha in your studies!

Comment: No worries @Shmuel we all have to start somewhere! Keep shteiging!

Comment: @Shmuel this says "Torah *and doing mitzvos.*" Are you looking for "Torah-study alone"?

Comment: @Shalom not per se. Both are welcome :)